# Bidirectional connection

Tags: communication

I want to know how can we have a bidirectional connection physically and electrically for example how can we send and receive signals at the same time in telephone wire without interference?
thanks for your answers!

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question like _at all_

Comment: please make yourself familiar with www.google.com and [ask]

Comment: excuse me for my irrelevant question.before my question i searched a lot and could not find my answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your question is off-topic the answer is pretty simple.
You have multiple wires. For a signal you need at least two. One for the signal and one to have a common reference the signal refers to.
So either you have at least 2 signal lines so you can send and receive at the same time or you have 1 signal line and both sides send/receive alternatingly.

Answer (score 0):

The term you are looking for is 'Full Duplex'.  Communications is a huge topic and it would take a book on the subject to give a complete answer for all cases, but we can generalise a simple answer.

I would not consider this completely off topic here as the same is true for example by two computer processes sending data between each other over some media, perhaps shared memory.

With very few exceptions, full duplex communications requires that there is some form of separation of the data on the channel between multiple parties.

Separation could be by frequency band, separate media (multiple carrier frequences, multiple wires or fibres), by time, coding scheme or other methods.  Search FM (frequency modulation - and variants thereof), TDMA (time division multiple access), CDMA (code division multiple access), etc.

In the care of analog telephones it's time; i.e. more than one person talking at the same time will have trouble understanding one another.

Analogue telepones are one of the few mediums where the data is not modulated on a carrier and the media is shared without any controls other than the individuals at each end cooporating.

Full duplex communication can introduce another problem; the send mechanism (e.g. microphone) can coupled to the receive mechanism (e.g. loudspeaker).
E.g. in the case of a phone this is by the media and the room each person is in. This means that because the two are coupled and it takes time to send the message to the other end, echo can be introduced which must be eliminated (echo cancellation) or the message will get corrupted by the returning delayed copy (the echo).